Как работает решение задачи "Number of Ways to Select Buildings"?
Как не пытался не могу понять почему этот код работает, не говоря о том, что не представляю как к такому решению вообще можно прийти.
Не могу принципиально понять связи между всеми действиями, почему если элемент с индексом i равен например нулю, то из массива количеств единиц до каждой позиции мы берем элемент с индексом i - 1, и умножаем на разность последнего элемента и элемента с индексом i, в чем логика в этой формуле? Я уже мысленно обошел цикл несколько раз с разными строками и логики уловить никакой не могу от слова совсем. Буду очень благодарен за любые объяснения.
    public long NumberOfWays(string s) {
        int n = s.Length;
        int[] count0 = new int[n];
        int[] count1 = new int[n];
        long totalWays = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i > 0) {
                count0[i] = count0[i - 1];
                count1[i] = count1[i - 1];
            }
            if (s[i] == '0') {
                count0[i]++;
            } else {
                count1[i]++;
            }
        }

        for (int j = 1; j < n - 1; j++) {
            if (s[j] == '0') {
                totalWays += count1[j - 1] * (count1[n - 1] - count1[j]);
            } else {
                totalWays += count0[j - 1] * (count0[n - 1] - count0[j]);
            }
        }

        return totalWays;
    }
}

Сама задача :
You are given a 0-indexed binary string s which represents the types of buildings along a street where:
s[i] = '0' denotes that the ith building is an office and
s[i] = '1' denotes that the ith building is a restaurant.
As a city official, you would like to select 3 buildings for random inspection. However, to ensure variety, no two consecutive buildings out of the selected buildings can be of the same type.
For example, given s = "001101", we cannot select the 1st, 3rd, and 5th buildings as that would form "011" which is not allowed due to having two consecutive buildings of the same type.
Return the number of valid ways to select 3 buildings.

Рассмотрите строку из единиц и нулей. Допустимые выборки из трёх элементов могут быть только двух видов - 1,0,1 и 0,1,0
На каждом шаге мы смотрим очередной элемент. Если это ноль, то он может быть центральным для выборки первого вида. Сколько вариантов есть для единиц слева?  count1[j - 1]. А справа - оставшиеся единицы (count1[n - 1] - count1[j]). Общее количество вариантов есть произведение этих чисел. Аналогично для центральной единицы и count0[]
P.S. Обратите внимание, что требования по памяти можно сократить в два раза, избавившись от одного из массивов (ведь count0[i]=i+1-count1[i]). А можно и вообще без дополнительной памяти, зная размер массива и количество единиц в нём, и подсчитывая левые единицы на основном ходу алгоритма.

Прямо гонки на ответах! :)

Благодарю за ответ, обязательно попробую сократить использование памяти)

Решение перебирает разные комбинации из трёх зданий начиная со среднего здания. Если среднее здание - офис (sj = 0), то первое и третье здания для инспекции должны быть рестораны. Число способов выбрать ресторан до позиции j равно count1[j - 1]. Число способов выбрать ресторан после позиции j равно count1[n - 1] - count1[j]. Если их перемножить, будет число всех допустимых комбинаций при условии sj = 0.
Среднее здание - ресторан обрабывается аналогично.
Если мы умеем считать число различных инспекций для средней позиции j, мы умеем считать число инспекций вообще - суммируя по j.

Набрал уже своё, жаль было выкидывать ;)

Благодарю за ответ, теперь в недоумении почему я к этому сам не пришел, логика кажется слишком простой
